# rubyrep Exception caught: PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed: show search_path

Tags: ruby, postgresql, replication

I am trying to use rubyrep to just scan between two databases and am getting the following error:

```
Exception caught: PG::ConnectionBad: connection is closed: show search_path
```

- rubyrep gem is 1.2.0
- pg gem is 0.17.1
- ruby 2.1.5

I have verified that from the command line (psql) I can connect and select from the databases.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have found out in order to make [rubyrep](http://www.rubyrep.org) work:

- The stock gem that comes with `gem install rubyrep` does not seem to work when in combnation with the latest pg gem. I have not tried using older versions of pg, because:
- Using [this fork](https://github.com/ncoders/rubyrep) of rubyrep seems to work.  You need to clone it with git and then run a `gem build rubyrep.gemspec` in order to build the gem locally. Then, you run `gem install ./rubyrep-XXXXXX.gem` and you are done.

I tried the above gem with both ruby 2.1.5 and jruby. It was equally painfully slow.

Comment: typo. 
`git build rubyrep.gemspec` -> `gem build rubyrep.gemspec`

Comment: Oh... typo again... `get` -> `gem`

Comment: ^$@^%R! Damn! I hope I've fixed this